# How do I set environment variable by importing from a file?

Tags: windows, bash, environment-variables

I know `set` command sets environment variables temporarily while `set` command sets environment variables permanently.

This command exports current environment variable `path` to a file

```
echo %path% > path.txt
```

Is there a way to set environment variable by importing from a file, something like this?

```
set %path% < path.txt
```

I tried `env:PATH = (Get-Content path.txt)` with powershell but got this error.

[image]

Comment: Is a powershell solution also welcomed?

Comment: You may want to revise the opening sentence :)

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio Yes. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Found a useful related question + answers over [on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72236585/13762264)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try the commands below to set/change the environment variable while reading it from a file. In the following example, the PATH variable is set and its content will be replaced.

```
$env:PATH = (Get-Content path.txt)
```

To add to the environment variable:

```
$env:PATH += (Get-Content path.txt)
```

You can also use `[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable` as described [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-powershell-1.0/ff730964(v=technet.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) to make the changes permanent.

```
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable($env:Path, $mypath, "Process")
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I updated my OP, would you please take a look at it?

Comment: @JJJohn You forgot the dollar sign in front of env:Path.